# How can I secure under counter sink studs to an existing granite counter top?

Tags: kitchen-sink, kitchen-counters

I have an under counter kitchen sink that has fallen. The original installer had it hanging on the bottom of the faucet. I've purchased gorilla glue ultimate construction adhesive and some "studs" that I should be able to glue to the bottom of the counter. I understand the construction adhesive is supposed to be good for this purpose, if I properly clean the granite. I've bought stripper and wire brushes to clean it. I've got 10 of the studs that have a sliding bracket and wing nuts I can use to support the sink. The construction adhesive is supposed to take up to 24 hours to cure. **How can I secure the studs so that adhesive has time to cure before applying weight? Is it necessary or is the cleaning, construction adhesive, and appropriate curing time sufficient?**

[image]

Picture of under side of my sink

[image]

Car jack holding it up
[image]

Comment: How about a few pictures of the problem so we can see what you see.

Comment: I wonder if there might be an "XY problem" here. I think you are asking about how to clamp wooden blocks to the granite, but unless you are very sure that that is the way to go, maybe you should ask something like "How do I reattach this undermount sink to my granite countertop?" In either case, you'll probably get better answers if you include some pictures of your sink and/or countertop hole where you will install it.

Comment: No, @MatthewBourque i'm not trying to clamp wooden blocks. I'm trying to glue the things I pictured to the underside of my granite countertop.

Comment: Good call on the picture @JACK so I've added a couple. It's kind of tight under there since the sink is still in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to hold them in place with anything. The construction adhesive is sticky enough that it should be able to hold the clamp while it cures. I would wait at least double the amount of time it says for the adhesive to cure before putting any load on them.

Comment: marking this one as answer because it did hold. it's strong enough. Because of limited space, I was only able to use 6 of 10 studs, re-using the secured wooden piece on the front side of the sink and the 6 studs on the back and one side.

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain specific two-part epoxy that countertop installers use to glue sinks under the counter.  I don't know the details but some research should help you find that, rather than other glues.

Remove the drain hardware from the sink.  Lay a 2x4 across the countertop opening.  Pull the sink up to the opening from below.  Using a large woodworking clamp, pass one end through the drain to grab the sink from beneath it, and the other end over top of the 2x4, and clamp the sink to the bottom of the counter.  Then work from beneath, securing the clamps to the counter with the epoxy.

There's LOTS of youtube tutorials on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sink has been removed, I would use clamps through the sink opening to hold the studs in place.

I would use an epoxy.

Comment: Sink has not been removed, just slightly fallen. I used a car jack to hold the sink up since it was secured on one side.

Comment: I hear the typical epoxy is not strong enough to really hold the studs on, plus it's subject to oils/dirt/grime causing poor seals. Home Depot's instructions recommend construction adhesive: 
https://www.homedepot.com/c/ah/how-to-install-an-undermount-sink-/9ba683603be9fa5395fab901f6bc77aa

"Use construction adhesive to glue the sink clip studs in place. Follow instructions for drying time. "

Comment: I would use an epoxy designed for the job. If you're going to use construction adhesive, I think @longneck's answer is a good one.